# How to find Influence function?

Tags: self-study, robust, influence-function

> Derive $IF(x;T,F)$ when
> $$\displaystyle T(F)=\int_{F^{-1}(\alpha)}^{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}x ~dF(x)$$
> Here $IF$ stands for Influence function.

Trial: Here $$\begin{align}IF(x;T,F) &=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{T((1-t)F+t\Delta_x)-T(F)}t \\ &=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{g(t)-g(0)}t=\frac{d}{dt}g(t)|_{t=0} \end{align}$$ Then I try to simplify $T(F)$ as $$\int_{F^{-1}(\alpha)}^{F^{-1}(1-\alpha)}x ~dF(x) \\ =\int_{\alpha}^{1-\alpha}F^{-1}(y) ~dy$$
Then I am stuck.

Comment: Try stepping back from the math a little... writing heuristically, how does $T(F)$ change for a small change in a value of $x < F^{-1}(\alpha)$?  How about for a small change in a value $x > F^{-1}(1-\alpha)$?

Comment: @jbowman Sorry. I don't understand. Can you explain it more briefly. Please.

Comment: What is the "derivative" of $T(F)$ (well, Gateaux variation in the direction of $\Delta_x$) for values of $x$ outside of the range $(F^{-1}(\alpha), F^{-1}(1-\alpha))$?